# Skyrim special edition crashing when leaving or getting near white run on xbox one

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Okay so i am having a problem with my skyrim special edition where everytime i get near white run or i try to leave white run via the main gate, my game crashes. I don't know what to do about it as I've already redone my mod load order several times. I have tried taking a carriage to white run and that hasn't worked either. I was wondering if anyone else was having this problem, and if they were able to fix it, if so help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try to disable one mod and try to get to whiterun again. If it still crashes disable another mod and try again, until it doesn't crash anymore so you know which mod causes this. Then you can activate the other mods again, and this time it should run.

Comment: This should solve it - most likely a mod conflict where one mod deletes something that another expects to be there. On the PC we have things like TESVEdit for such eventualities - the Xbox only recieves partial mod support, regretably.